# Refreshtokenexpiry for Google Oauth App Internal / Testing

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api, google-oauth, azure-data-factory

i came across a often mentioned problem with the Google API and refresh tokens when in publishing status "Testing".

In my case i am trying to use Azure Datafactory to connect to Google BigQuery. The App was created rather quickly as well as the needed refreshtoken for ADF and for 7 days i can use the token but then it expires as [stated by Google](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?authuser=1&hl=de#user-type&zippy=%2Ctesting)

> Authorizations by a test user will expire seven days from the time of consent. If your OAuth client requests an offline access type and receives a refresh token, that token will also expire.

I know that i can publish the app, but as it is an internal Project, and the verification process takes some time, I was asking myself, if putting the app up as only "Internal" User Type, would have the same outcome?
What would be the "right" combination of app types to achieve that the refresh token expires like in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration), Internal/Testing or Internal/Production or is this not possible without verification at all?

Answer (score 0):

Per this [SO pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745134/how-do-i-test-refreshing-my-google-access-token-using-a-refresh-token)t, one way to handle this testing is by simply making note of an expired access_token. Then when you need to test how your app deals with an expired token you can give the app that expired token to work with. This way, for example, you can test that requests with an expired token will fail as expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but i am not looking to test my tokens but the publishing status of the app is "Testing" opposed to "In production". 
I'm interested in knowing, when i change the user type from external to internal, whether the refreshtoken still would be revoked after 7 days or if lasts longer in internal use.